# Which Ubuntu should I install for >8GB RAM?

Tags: 64-bit, hardware, ram, 32-bit

I have tried Ubuntu 64 bits and have many issues, among them the computer ran a lot slower than with 32 bits.

I want to buy a >8GB RAM computer and I'm considering which version of Ubuntu to use.

I have heard something about Ubuntu 32 bits with PAE, or Ubuntu 64 bits.

Which version will work best?

Comment: there's no reason to use PAE http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ubuntu_32_pae&num=1 https://cl4ssic4l.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/linus-torvalds-about-pae/

Comment: 64-bit version should run faster than 32-bit version in most cases. There are tons of benchmarks out there.

Comment: Yeah, that was a few years ago (5).

Answer (score 5):

I would use Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. They have really worked out most (all?) of the 32 vs 64 bit issues in the last few releases. I have been running 11.04 and 12.04 64-bit on several of our machines at work, and have not had any architectural related issues so far.

Comment: I haven't noticed any problems I can associate with 64 bit either. Very happy.

Comment: Indeed, while the PAE version will let you access all your RAM, *each program* will still be limited to using a very small fraction of it. (PAE [doesn't](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingPAE) provide Virtual Address Extension.) On a 64-bit system, there is no such limitation, and [multarch](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiArch) makes even 32-bit applications work easily on 64-bit Ubuntu.